# generating random numbers with limits

Tags: c, random

What is the easiest way to generate 5 random numbers from 1 to 200 such that

```
 randnum[0] < randnum[1] < randnum[2] < randnum[3] < randnum[4]
```

My code looks like this but it always overflows at randnum[4]

```
 limit_upper = 10; // generate random number up to 10 for randnum[0] 
 limit_lower = 0;

 srand((time(0));


 for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
         randnum[x] = 1 + limit_lower + (unsigned int) rand() % limit_upper;
         limit_lower = limit_lower + randnum[x];
         limit_upper = (limit_upper * 2) + (unsigned int) rand() % limit_upper;
 }
```

The random numbers to be generated should not repeat.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: why did the other answer with pseudo code, disappeared? i will be going to choose it as the accepted answer. did the author deleted it?

Comment: Yes, possibly because it was generating random numbers that were not in the range 1..200. The first number was in the range 1..200, but then the second was only random between let's say 35..200.

Comment: just generate 5 random numbers and order greatest to least them then with that same array create a for loop to place them in the desires 5 arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate random numbers from 1 to 200, sort them as you go, discard duplicates, until you have 5.

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirement of strict <.

Comment: Yes, agreed, just sort as you go and re-generate as you go, until you have enough uniques.

Answer (score 1):

As azhrei pointed out, you're over complicating things.  Generate five random numbers between 0 and 200 while throwing out duplicates and sort when finished.  This will work well unless you're planning on expanding your code significantly beyond five numbers or have some crazy performance requirements.  You'll thank yourself later for the straight forward readable bug-free code.  Also, you will remove any artificial limitations to your randomness.

Comment: I generally disagree. When you write code with performance that can explode when parameters change in reasonable ways, you're setting a maintainer up for a future problem. If we needed to generate 180 random selections in [1..200], we'd probably not want your algorithm.

Comment: Thus my comment about expanding the number of randoms required.  Thus my comment about performance requirements.  What my algorithm has that others haven't provided yet though is true randomness.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer sugggests, here is the solution:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

     void quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
             int i = left, j = right;
             int tmp;
             int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

             while (i <= j) {
                     while (arr[i] < pivot)
                             i++;
                     while (arr[j] > pivot)
                             j--;

                     if (i <= j) {
                             tmp = arr[i];
                             arr[i] = arr[j];
                             arr[j] = tmp;
                             i++;
                             j--;
                     }

             };

             if (left < j)

             quicksort(arr, left, j);

             if (i < right)

             quicksort(arr, i, right);

     }

     int main() {
             int i;
             int x;
             int random[5];

             srand(time(0));

             for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                     random[i] = 0;
             }


             for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                     random[i] = rand() % 201;
                     for (x = 1; x < i; x++) {
                             if (random[x] == random[i]) {
                                     i--;
                                     continue;
                             }
                     }
             }

             quicksort(random, 0, 4);

             for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                     printf("random[%0d]: %0d \n", i, random[i]);
             }

             return 0;
     }
```

Maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your last line, limit_upper could become anything up to 267 by the 3rd iteration.

The max increase being limit_upper*2 + limit_upper-1 (about 3*limit_upper).

That you get the same problem every time are you seeding your random generator?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem covered from several angles by Jon Bentley in [Programming Perls](http://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&lpg=PA126&ots=DgvTvUwU7v&dq=selection%20without%20replacement%20algorithm%20bentley&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q=selection%20without%20replacement%20algorithm%20bentley&f=false).  I highly recommend this book.

Comment: That can produce equal values.

Comment: I erased the code because it's explained better in Bentley's book. The bug was that < should have been <=.  If you think about it for a while you'll see why this can't produce a duplicate. Or see the book.